# Does Adobe media encoder work if you have the cracked version of Adobe After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, editing, adobe, adobe-media-encoder

My friend has the cracked version, but for some reason, he cannot link his media encoder to his after effects software. How can he fix this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about improper use of software

Answer (score 3):

Tell your friend that good software costs money. And is made by developers who need to put food on the table.